# Javascript HTA ADODB Connection on Windows 10 / IE 11

Tags: javascript, adodb, hta

I have a long standing HTA that was working perfect on a Windows 8 machine running IE 10.

Since upgrading to Windows 10 / IE 11 the application can now longer talk to a SQL database using the same codebase.

Previously this code worked perfectly :

```
var connectionstring = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xxxxx;Database=x;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxx";

this.getDataFromDB = function (SQLQuery, returnType)
{
    if (Logger) Logger.StartLogItem(Logger.newLoggerMessage("DB COMS - CONFIG DATABASE", "Getting data from config DB : SQL Command Sent -  " + SQLQuery, LogEntryType.Task));
    var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 20;
    conn.CommandTimeout = 20;
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

    try
    {
        conn.Open(connectionstring);
        rs.Open(SQLQuery, conn);
        var respObj = { data: [] };
        while (!rs.EOF)
        {
            switch (returnType)
```

However now it gets to the conn.Open(connectionstring) and then fails with :

**Error Extracting Data from Database :
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].**

The only way I have been able to get round this is to manually create a DSN in the ODBC Data Source Administration in Control Panel and then use the connection string :

```
var connectionstring = "DSN=FCMADMIN;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd=xxxxx;"
```

Then everything works perfectly again!

So why can't I use the old connection string.  I'm unsure if it's a Windows 10 issue or IE 11.  The issue is - this app gets rolled out to 1000's of workstation, so don't really want to get them to create a ODBC User Data Source on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - stupid schoolboy error.
At the same time, the server name changed to contain an instance i.e it became SQLServer\Instance1

When entering that into the connection string I had forgotten to escape the slash !!!!!

When I changed it to SQLServer\Instance1 it all started working!